# Does the last scene of ST:DS9 "The Passenger" involve an illegal / immoral execution?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the [DS9: The Passenger](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Passenger_(episode)), a Kobliad criminal is being transported somewhere by another Kobliad, Ty Kajada. Eventually the criminal's consciousness is moved to a storage device, and once Sisko releases him back to Ty Kajada's control, she immediately vaporizes the device while the Federation crew looks on admiringly.

- Was Kajada authorized to execute the criminal?
- Should the DS9/Federation crew have allowed that to happen?

Comment: It's more like a "mind wipe", kinda like the "Death of Personality" in Babylon 5

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: @Luke The meory Alpha page states " Sisko's expression indicates he is a little unsettled by her cold-blooded "execution" of Vantika" Im not sure where the admirably came from.

Comment: @Rainbow - I rewatched the scene. He looks surprised at first, but then Sisko, Bashir, and Dax all exchange a very subtle smile - maybe a nervous smile, maybe a smile of happiness. Kajada walks off and none of them stop her or make any sign of protest.

Answer (score 8):

No canon one way or another as to whether she was authorized to execute the criminal although if she was authorized to execute him it could be asked why she was transporting him in the first place.  with that being said what she did may not qualify as an execution a stored consciousness may not be a legal entity.

As to the DS9 crew allowing the thing that may of may not have been an execution, for the most part The Federation respects the laws of other cultures except when a main character is breaking them and some soapboxing about how The Federation is better because they dont lock their deviants away or execute them so sure they really would have had no reason or obligation to stop it beyond perhaps a polite request not to do it on the promenade.

Comment: stored consciousnesses must have reduced rights compared to physical entities or else purging the transporter buffer would be seen as equivalent to murder of everyone ever transported by that transporter

Answer (score 6):

Vantika's experiments were highly, y'know, experimental, which means that it's unlikely that the Kobliad have any law that covers the legal rights of a stored consciousness (in precisely the way that we don't have any relevant laws that cover a similar situation).

Vantika has been declared dead by the appropriate authorities on DS9. She's merely asserting her right to destroy something that is, for all intents and purposes, a non-living object.

> **BASHIR:** *Our prisoner?  He's dead.*
>
> **KAJADA:** *You're certain.*
>
> **BASHIR:** *Yes. You were the only survivor.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Passenger - Original Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/409.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: I imagine there are some Federation reporting requirements when a ship is hijacked, and they'd have to admit the criminal's consciousness was still alive.

Comment: @Luke - Weeeelll. It's hard to say if it was alive or not. And after the fact, it definitely wasn't. At best you could describe it as a consciousness. I dare say you could also argue that it was merely an electronic virus capable of taking over a person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ty broke a Federation aspect: respect for sentient life, and effectively committed murder of a Kobliad citizen within Federation space. A storage of consciousnessces meets all the [aspects of consciousness](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sentience#Aspects_of_consciousness) (free will, etc etc). In fact, the Federation goes to great lengths to [preserve evil computers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_Pleasant_Fountains_Lie_(episode)#:%7E:text=Ultimately%2C%20AGIMUS%20is%20delivered%20as%20planned%20and%20locked%20in%20the%20%22Self%2DAware%20Megalomaniacal%20Computer%20Storage%22%20section%20alongside%20numerous%20other%20sentient%20computers.) as seen in the ending of ST:LD *Where Pleasant Fountains Lie*, AGIMUS is stored with hundreds of other evil computers.

Comment: Well ST:LD is a comedy where everything's played for laughs - like as if the producer of "Family Guy" came to them and said "let me take a swing at Star Trek" and they laughed and went "wow, what would THAT be like"... and then did it... anyway making that canon would be nuts.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica My headcanon regarding the canonicity of ST:LD is that the episodes we see are something like war stories Mariner tells in a bar - there is underlying truth it, but the weirdness is just Mariner being Mariner.

Comment: “Showrunner Mike McMahan assured fans that [ST:LD was canon] at a symposium at Star Trek Las Vegas in 2019.” https://www.cbr.com/star-trek-lower-decks-canon/amp/

Comment: Star Trek: Lower Decks is garbage.